# Splitting Code in different Files - Python / App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, optimization

I have multiple classes and everything is in a single main.py file which is getting really messy...

I'm new to Python however I've taken a couple of courses now and I'm getting quite good but in none of the lessons was a reference on how to do this...

The main problem I have is I don't understand how splitting code works in Python and what I have to re-import in every file... So rather then an answer I would love some documentation or preferably a video tutorial on this.

I'll give you some sample code:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler, usersHandler, postsHandler):
class usersHandler(DdHandler):
class DdHandler():
```

I want to have each class in a separate file kinda like Java and C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for how to divide your code into modules: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

You might not always want one file for each class, but rather a logical grouping of classes.
In your case you might have a file named db.py where you put usersHandler and DbHandler

In your main file you would then do something like

```
import db

db_handler = db.DbHandler()
```

Also keep in mind that class names should start with an upper case, UsersHandler instead of usersHandler. See more conventions at http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: I will dw hehe. Will have to wait 7 more mins